# How to prevent iOS Safari from converting decimal value to telephone link

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

iOS Safari automatically converts numbers like 102.0000 or 1,374.1400 to telephone links. The first number, which is inside a `<td>`, is converted to `<td><a href="tel:102.0000">102.0000</a></td>`, the second, which is also inside a `<td>`, is converted to `<td>"1,"<a href="tel:374.1400">374.1400</a></td>`. Annoying.

In the `<head>`er I've included the following: `<meta name="format-detection” content=”telephone=no" />`. It does not work.

Other than perhaps wrapping the decimal point between `<span>` or `<label>` tags, or encoding it to `&#46;`, all hacks I've seen in some sites, is there any other **easier** way to prevent the automatic conversion of a number (###.####) into a telephone link in iOS?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked if it detects them with the meta tag on other browsers? <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"> works just fine for me at the moment. Could be a spelling error? Or an error with the " " marks?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Sometimes, when in the weeds, I fail to look for stupid little things, like the " marks, which you mentioned. Two of them were wrong! Probably the result of copy/paste from a site. Yikes. Thank you, again.

Comment: No problem :) Im glad you got it solved